# Навигация к открытому файлу в хроме

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

Работаю в `phpstorm 2016.2.1` и в хроме. При обновлении страницы проекта в хроме, переключаюсь на `phpstorm` а он пытается показать мне где находится открытый файл и переключается на папку в которой он лежит. Я работаю с `Laravel` и при переключении на `phpstorm` вижу следующую картину в древе директорий:

[image: непонятная навигация к файлу]

На данном скрине видно, как после переключения через `alt+tab` с хрома на `phpstorm`, он переключился на директорию `storage/framework/cache/c0` . Т.е. он мне показывает, где хранится открытая страница в хроме, но она берется из кэша и такое поведение у `phpstorm` мне вообще не нужно. Как отключить автонавигацию к папке после переключения с хрома?

Answer (score 1):

Я использую опцию автоскроллинга от изменяемого файла в навигации.
Т.е. в окошке навигации файлов, справа от "**Project Files**" вы можете найти кнопку настройки с выпадающем меню.

Отключите опцию "**Autoscroll from Source**".
Вот так это выглядит у меня:

[image: Autoscroll from Source - Если эта опция включена, то PhpStorm автоматически навигирует из файла в эдиторе к соответсвующему узлу (file, class, field, method, итд.) в окне инструментов проекта(Project tool window).]

Так же попробуйте отключить слежение за файлами кеша путём *исключения* папки:

правой кнопкой мыши жмём на папку кеша(допустим `storage/framework/cache`) > выбераем **Mark Directory As** > **Excluded**

Полезные ссылки по вашей проблеме:

- [Описание бага WI-32041](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32041)
- [Дискуссия проблемы](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207604765-How-to-avoid-the-autoscroll-in-project-file-window-)
- [Документация - project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/project-tool-window.html)